# Re-prompt after an exception in Java

Tags: java, exception

I remember having this exact issue in Python. This Java code is a replica of my Python code which calculates the area of a triangle. I have it catch an exception if a non-number value is entered, but the end result gets botched.

```
private static float baseLength() {
    float baseLength = 0;
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    try {
        while (baseLength <= 0) {
            System.out.print("Enter the base length of the triangle: ");
            baseLength = user_input.nextFloat();
            if (baseLength <=0) {
                System.out.println("Error. Plase enter a number higher than 0.");
            }
        }            
    } catch (InputMismatchException badChar) {   
        System.err.println("You have entered a bad value. Please try again");
        baseLength();
    }
    return baseLength;
```

It will recover from bad numbers, but not from a value that is not a number. I still can't figure out what the exact issue is.

Comment: you might want `return baseLength()` instead of just calling it.

Comment: what is the issue here? I tested it.It seems to be working fine.What is the expected behaviour here?

Comment: When a user puts in a number 0 or below, it will prompt them again. However, if a user types in 'dog' for example, it will still prompt them again, but the return value is not the number you think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with tests more clear, and exception inside principal loop, and every errors with System.err

```
private static float baseLength() {
   float baseLength = 0;

   while (true)
   {
   try {
       System.out.print("Enter the base length of the triangle: ");

        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        baseLength = user_input.nextFloat();

        if (baseLength>0)
           return baseLength;

        if (baseLength <=0)
               System.err.println("Error. Plase enter a number higher than 0.");
       } 
       catch (InputMismatchException badChar)
       {   
       System.err.println("You have entered a bad value. Please try again");
       }
   }
 }
```

Comment: I ran multiple tests with this code and it works! So the issue with my code was that I just needed to split it into multiple statements to make sure it catches all scenarios individually. I will keep this in mind in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the `while` loop around the try/catch block to achieve this:

```
private static float baseLength() {
    float baseLength = 0;
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (baseLength <= 0) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Enter the base length of the triangle: ");
            baseLength = user_input.nextFloat();
            if (baseLength <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Error. Plase enter a number higher than 0.");
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException badChar) {
            System.err.println("You have entered a bad value. Please try again");
        }
    }
    return baseLength;
}
```

Comment: I ran some tests with this code. The 'baseLength <= 0' catches work correctly, but if I type in 'cow' it will recursively print the error message.

Comment: That's strange, because my code omits your now unnecessary recursive call